# Using `mailapp.sendemail` with `replyto` option

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to send an email like this:

```
 MailApp.sendEmail(passa[3], rispondiA, sogg, {htmlBody: corpo});
```

`passa[3]` contains the recipient email address

`rispondiA` contains the email address for the replyTo option.

`sogg` contains the subject of the email.

`corpo` contains the email body.

Everything works fine, except that the email I receive shows the replyTo email address as the subject, and the replyTo function doesn't work.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Since you are using htmlBody then the second parameter is the subject look at the documentation

Comment: `MailApp.sendEmail(passa[3], sogg,'', {htmlBody: corpo, replyTo: rispondiA});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, googleing I found the solution:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(passa[3], sogg, corpo, {htmlBody: corpo, replyTo: rispondiA});
```

Sorry for this.